# Got XML validation error: cvc-complex-type.2.4.e

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I got the following schema error when doing XSD validation:

---

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.e: Unexpected element. Element "AAA" is not one
>   of the choices.

---

Below is the section in XSD which causes failure (The entire schema is too long):

```
<xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"> 
   <xsd:element name="AAA" type="AAAType"/>
   <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="BBB" type="BBBType"/>
</xsd:sequence>
```

The XML being validated is as follows:

```
<Message>
   ......
   <AAA>
      ......
   </AAA>
</Message>
```

Can someone help me find out what is the reason?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You've elided too much of the XSD and XML for us to tell what's wring.

Comment: Please show a complete, minimal example of both your XSD and your XML instance document. Help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.